# Find a function value given 2 points

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

Given $f(x)$, which is differentiable at every point such that: $f'(x) \ge -5$ for every $ x \in R$

$f(2) = -13$, $f(9) = -48$

Prove that:$ f(3) = -18$

Now it's quite obvious that $ f(3) = -18$ since that if we know that the **lowest** value of the derivative is -5, the difference between $f(2)$ and $f(9)$ is $-48-(-13)=-35$

that means that that in the area $[2,9]$, $f'(x)=-5$ right?
that's why I told that $f(3) = -18$, but I feel that my proof is insufficient, probably because I'm missing some theorems or such. can someone help me structure this proof into something RIGHT :)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I'm not mistaking if derivative is always positive then the function is strictly increasing

Comment: What does this mean that it's strictly increasing? How it is helpful?

Comment: It means that for every $x>y$ we have that $f(x)>f(y)$.Here's a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) article.

Comment: I still can't see how it is helpful in this problem

Comment: Than your function doesn't satisfy $f(9)>f(2)$ so $f'(x)\not\geq 5$ for every $x$

Comment: I accidently wrote the problem wrong, fixed it now, it is strictly decreasing, but I can't see how it helps to build the proof

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, and you can formalize your proof using the
["mean value theorem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem):

$$
\begin{align}
  f(3) &= f(2) + (3 - 2)f'(c) \quad &\text{ for some } c \in (2, 3) \\
       &= -13 + f'(c) \\
       & \ge -13 - 5 \quad &\text{ because } f'(c) \ge -5 \\
       &= -18
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
  f(3) &= f(9) + (3 - 9)f'(d)  \quad&\text{ for some } d \in (3, 9) \\
       &= -48 -6 \, f'(d) \\
       & \le -48 -30 \quad &\text{ because } f'(d) \ge -5\\
       &= -18 \quad .
\end{align}
$$
It follows that $f(3) = 18$.

In the same way you can show that $f(x) = -5x - 3$ for all $x \in [2, 9]$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that the function satisfies $$\frac{f(x_1 )-f(x_2 ) }{x_1 - x_2} =k.$$ k is constant.

Reason why I added it to Answers section, is because I could not add comment.