# Let $f$ be a differentiable function with $|f'(x)|\leq1$ and $f(-3)=-3, f(3)=3$. Then find $f(0)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function with $|f'(x)|\leq1$ and $f(-3)=-3, f(3)=3$. Then find $f(0)$.

I think this is mean value theorem problem. But I can't solve... help me please.

Comment: You can use the same techniques as in [Find a function value given 2 points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108314/find-a-function-value-given-2-points) – does this count as a duplicate?.

Comment: $f(0) = f(3) - 3f'(\xi)  = 3(1-f'(\xi)) \ge 0$.  $f(0) = f(-3) +3f'(\eta) = -3(1 - f'(\eta)) \le 0$.  Therefore $f(0) = 0$,

Answer (score 2):

MVT states that there exists a unspecified c between a and b such that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} $$

1. Apply MVT between endpoints -3 and 0:
   There exists c1, between -3 and 0, ie $ -3 \leq c1 \leq 0 $, such that

$$ f'(c1) = \frac{f(0)-f(-3)}{0-(-3)} $$

$$ f'(c1) = \frac{f(0)+3}3  $$

but $ |f'(c1)|\leq 1$

$$ \left|\frac{f(0)+3}3\right| \leq 1 $$

$$ |f(0)+3| \leq 3 $$

There are two cases to this: whether or not f(0)+3 is negative or positive.

$$ \text{case a)} \quad f(0)+3 \geq0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{case b)} \quad f(0)+3 \leq 0 $$

$$ (f(0) +3) \leq 3 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad -(f(0) +3) \geq -3$$

$$ (f(0) +3) \leq 3 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad -f(0) -3 \geq -3 $$

$$ f(0) \leq 0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad -f(0) \geq 0 $$

$$ f(0) \leq 0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad f(0) \leq 0 $$

$$ f(0) \leq 0 $$

2. Now apply MVT between endpoints 0 and 3:
   There exists c2, between 0 and 3, ie $ 0 \leq c2 \leq 3 $, such that

$$ f'(c2) = \frac{f(3)-f(0)}{3-0} $$

$$ f'(c2) = \frac{3 - f(0)}3  $$

$$ \left|\frac{3 - f(0)}3\right| \leq 1 $$

$$ |3 - f(0)| \leq 3 $$

There are also two cases to this: whether or not 3 - f(0) is negative or positive.

$$ \text{case a)} \quad 3 - f(0) \geq0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{case b)} \quad 3 - f(0) \leq 0 $$

$$ (3 - f(0)) \leq 3 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad -(3 - f(0)) \geq -3$$

$$ -f(0) \leq 0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad -3 +f(0) \geq -3 $$

$$ f(0) \geq 0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad f(0) \geq 0 $$

$$ f(0) \geq 0 $$

Combining  $ f(0) \leq 0 \text{ and } f(0) \geq 0 $

$$ 0 \leq f(0) \leq 0 $$

Then by the squeeze theorem $ f(0) = 0 $.

Comment: The triangle inequality would be $ |f(0)+3| \le |f(0)| +|3| $ and not the other way around. Also it seems that you are not using $f(3)=3$, so there must be same flaw in the argument.

Comment: Oh my. You are correct. I'll have to rethink this.

Answer (score 2):

Since $|f'(x)|\leq 1$ then we take $f'(x)\leq 1$

1) integrate both sides from $-3$ to $u$

$\int_{-3}^uf'(x)dx\leq \int_{-3}^udx$

gives

$f(u)-f(-3)\leq u+3$

then
$f(u)\leq u$

2)integrate both sides from $u$ to $3$

$\int_{u}^3f'(x)dx\leq \int_{u}^3dx$

gives

$f(3)-f(u)\leq 3-u$

then
$-f(u)\leq -u$
which simply gives

$f(u)\geq u$

..
combine step 1 and 2

$u\leq f(u)\leq u$

implies that $f(u)=u$ and $f(0)=0$